# How to use pd.qcut in python to decile column for column values > 0

Tags: python, pandas, bins

Column contains following data (Data has been sorted in descending order of this column). There are two million records in this column and about one million are zeros. The distribution of this column is as follows

```
Column Distribution
min 0
mean 4.199
25% 0
50% 0
75% 0
max 1.400000
```

So basically there is data only in top 25% after sorting in descending order. I want to create equal sized bins for the data below after removing the zeros and binning the data only where column values are greater than > 0

```
enter code here

Column
1400000
97000
79000
43000
28000
11000
... so on 
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

I want to bin the data into deciles for only column_values > 0. Or I would like to force all zeros in one bin. Currently the issue I am facing is that the data in top 2 bins is containing 1.5 million and 50 thousand. Rest 8 bins are 0, 0, 0, .... i.e. when I look at the sum of the column grouped by bins.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can mask the column and apply qcut:

```
s = pd.Series([0,0,0,0,0] + [*range(10)])
pd.qcut(s.where(s>0), np.linspace(0,1,10))
```

Output:

```
0                NaN
1                NaN
2                NaN
3                NaN
4                NaN
5                NaN
6     (0.999, 1.889]
7     (1.889, 2.778]
8     (2.778, 3.667]
9     (3.667, 4.556]
10    (4.556, 5.444]
11    (5.444, 6.333]
12    (6.333, 7.222]
13    (7.222, 8.111]
14      (8.111, 9.0]
dtype: category
Categories (9, interval[float64]): [(0.999, 1.889] < (1.889, 2.778] < (2.778, 3.667] < (3.667, 4.556] ... (5.444, 6.333] < (6.333, 7.222] < (7.222, 8.111] < (8.111, 9.0]]
```

Or `quantile`:

```
s.where(s>0).quantile(np.linspace(0,1,5))
```

Output:

```
0.00    1.0
0.25    3.0
0.50    5.0
0.75    7.0
1.00    9.0
dtype: float64
```